# 2005 Silverado 1500 Brakes Dragging Randomly

Tags: brakes, chevrolet, abs, silverado, rwd

I have an 05 Silverado 1500 RWD, I have had an issue with my brakes for months now. My brakes tend to drag at least once a day, the pedal is very inconstant as well. It gets stiff and very close to the top of the pedal when I notice the drag. I have found that it is making my truck feel sluggish at times when it is acting up(can feel that the brakes are dragging, slowing the truck down) and then normal other times. I have replaced both calipers, rubber hoses, the MC, the rear drums with the cylinders and all, and after about 4k miles if that, my brake pads are gone on the insides. I have no other idea what to get it fixed, besides maybe replace the booster or the ABS module. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Usually this is a sign the calipers are not sliding correctly. I'd check the caliper pins. They should be greased and move without issue. If they don't, replace them.

Comment: I have checked everything multiple times and am not sure what to do from here. I have greased the slide pins as well, that didnt seem to help the situation either.'

Comment: It could be a malfunctioning ABS unit, and sometimes they set no codes.

Comment: @Moab I just got the ABS module bled and it seems to have helped the dragging issue. I haven't gotten to drive it but 2 miles, but the pedal seems more consistent and solid. So I've got my fingers crossed that I don"t need a new ABS assembly.